# Select tags ordered by popularity from many to many relation

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, many-to-many

I have three tables with many to many relation. Tables are simple: movies, tags and movietags (definition below). I'd like users to be able to see what are the most popular tags. Here's working query:

```
SELECT tags.tag, COUNT( * ) AS c, tags.id
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN movietags ON tags.id = tagid
GROUP BY tags.id
ORDER BY c DESC
```

So the result is like (tag name, count, tags.id)

```
action   450  2
comedy   300 10
drama    280  8
thriller 250  5
etc.
```

Many movies have many tags assigned. I'd like users to be able to choose their favorite tag. For example if user chooses "action" from above list, should get most popular tags among movies with "action" tag. The result would be like below - movies only with "action" tag:

```
comedy   120 10
thriller  88  5
western   62 21
drama     41  8
```

Now I can't adapt my query above to have WHERE clause without an error. How can I select and count movies only with "action" category? Also, I'd like users to choose from more tags, like selecting movies with "action", "thriller" and "comedy" tags, also ordered by count of movies with these tags.

Definitions of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned,
  `title` varchar(250),
  `tags` varchar(250),
  `category` varchar(250),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;


CREATE TABLE `movietags` (
  `tagid` int(10) unsigned,
  `movieid` int(10) unsigned,
  UNIQUE KEY `tagid_2` (`tagid`,`movieid`),
  KEY `mainid` (`movieid`),
  KEY `tagid` (`tagid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned auto_increment,
  `tag` varchar(250),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE tags.id=5     

The query is: SELECT tags.tag, COUNT( * ) AS c, tags.id
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN movietags ON tags.id = tagid
GROUP BY tags.id
ORDER BY c DESC 
WHERE tags.id =5

Answer (score 2):

As for your syntax error, the WHERE goes before the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT tags.tag, COUNT( * ) AS c, tags.id
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN movietags ON tags.id = tagid
WHERE tags.id =5
GROUP BY tags.id 
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: To let people select more than one tag, use:
     WHERE tags.id in (5,6,7,8).  

IN clauses are tough to parameterize.

Comment: Thanks, no syntax error now! But what I get now is result with one row only, with this tag id and counted movies having it. If I use WHERE ...IN I get only entries with specified ID, so part of the initial query, which is logical to me now. What I'd like to get is list of movies which have these tags among other tags.

Comment: select * from movies m, movietags t where m.id = t.movieid and t.id in (5,6,7,8)

Comment: Thanks, this one I had already. The thing is I need to count how many movies have these tags and order it by popularity. For example if I choose tags id 5,6 -- for example "action" and "comedy", I'd like to see what different tags have movies with these two tags, also sorted by popularity (count).